# CKEditor 4: How to get and set the cursor / caret position?

Tags: text, insert, ckeditor, position, cursor

I am looking for a way to do 2 very basic things. I just want to retrieve the position of the caret in the text. Then I want to position the caret in a specific position in the text. The purpose is to be able to programmatically modify the text.

I have found many people who were trying to do various similar things but not quite what I wanted. In fact, most solutions are looking into the HTML, finding ranges and DOM elements. Maybe that is the way to go but I haven't found a working solution.

Looking at getting the cursor position. I found the following solution from various sources ([this one](https://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/get-cursor-position-ckeditor) for example):

```
var selection = e.editor.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRanges()[0];
var cursor_position = range.startOffset;
```

But this does not respond to my problem. In the following text:

> Apple
>
> Archers
>
> Accent

If the cursor is put successively directly after the A of each word, it returns 1 each time. What I would want is to get 1 when positioned after the 1st A, then 6 when positioned after the 2nd A, then finally 13 after the 3rd.

In other words, it is more a matter of which character position is the cursor at in the text. It should allow me to insert text after the Xth character in the text for example.

Thank you for helping

Comment: In order to get cursor position you need to play with selection and ranges. Please note however you will not get the 1,6,13 result you expect because **CKEditor uses HTML in background** and not plain text. If your task is to return cursor position in pain text ignoring the HTML, please get yourself ready for a lot of frustration and pain because you will definitely get into many edge cases.

Comment: Hello @j.swiderski, thanks for your answer. Actually, I don't mind playing with ranges and selection so long that I get to the expected result. But so far, I don't see how. I illustrated the result by a count of letters but it is the same to me to have the position described as "Row1/Range3/Offset4", so long that it allows to return the cursor exactly where it was (in user language "after a letter in a word"). Ranges alone (like in the given example code) don't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: Please see https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-range and an old one https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-introduction as it has IMHO good examples and better definitions. In general each range has a starting node (startContainer) and an offset within that starting node. **Offsets are relative to startContainer** and don't show position in whole document. If you have collapsed selection in either Apple or Archers e.g. `<body><p>A^pple</p><p>A^rchers</p></body>` then offset is relative to paragraph (range startContainer) and not e.g. body.

Comment: @j.swiderski Sorry for the long absence, I was pulled away from this and here I am back. Thank you for your help. It really clarified the way the whole range system works and I understand clearly now that the offset is relative to startContainer. But that means that to return the caret to a specific position, I need to store the startContainer and the offset right? How would you suggest I do that? I need to save something in a DB so that I can come back to this point at any time.

Comment: Hi Xosted. Sorry for late reply. I think you would need to think of something like bookmarks in CKEditor. The editor bookmarks get removed when you switch to source mode and back or save data into DB thus you would need your own solution. I will post an answer because I need to add some comment there.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your last comment, **you might want to try implementing something like bookmarks in CKEditor but more durable**. As I have explained, the original bookmarks are removed when you post data to server or simply switch to source mode and back. What is more, empty spans which I would suggest using, are removed by the editor because they have no visual representation and are considered garbage.

What you can do is using `protectedSource` to protect your custom bookmark spans:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    language: 'en',
    protectedSource :  /<span.*class="my-break-point".*\/>/g
});
```

Next you would need to come up with custom code which will insert `<span class="my-break-point"/>` into editor HTML whenever you need it and keep track of bookmarks so that it removes previous one when next is inserted.

Of course this is just a basic example. You can have a bookmark for collapsed selection or two bookmarks for start/end of selection if selection is not collapsed.

Please try inserting bookmarks first and see what is inserted into HTML for collapsed and non-collapsed selections:
- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-createBookmark
 - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-createBookmark2

Sample code:

```
var range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
var bm = range.createBookmark();
```

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I started to play with the bookmarks to see what was happening. At first it looked perfect but indeed, they are not durable. I can serialize the bookmark object and save it in the db, but I can't get back to this bookmark if I reload the document (even if it was saved as well).
Creating my own bookmarks is the next step. I will try what you suggested. However I feel like I still don't understand why it is so hard to get the "address" of the caret in the document (or the node tree).

Comment: To put a bookmark at the right place, I need the position of the caret in the document (its "address") in what ever shape or form it would come. I don't understand why I can't simply save this "address" information in a db and later get back to this point.