# CKEditor 4: How to save and restore the cursor / caret position?

Tags: html, dom, ckeditor, range, ckeditor4.x

I know that there are some similar questions posted here but none seemed to answer my problematic (or maybe it is that I don't understand well the concept). I started by wanting to get and set the caret position within a CKeditor instance (question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743411/ckeditor-4-how-to-get-and-set-the-cursor-caret-position)). With help, I understood that I needed to use ranges and offsets to achieve this goal.

However my problem now is that I don't know how to save this position somewhere, possibly a database and restore the position of the caret. You can imagine a user modifying a document and saving it. When he comes back to continue the edition, the document should be loaded and the caret returned to the last known position.

So, to get the caret position from CKeditor in javascript, that is ok. I can get my range object. But how do I save it? How do I send it to the server for storing? How do I get it back? As a string?
Are there mechanisms to serialize and deserialize ranges or dom nodes?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> Are there mechanisms to serialize and deserialize ranges or dom nodes?

There is a mechanism called `bookmarks` in CKEditor 4. You can use [`CKEDITOR.dom.range.createBookmark`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-createBookmark), which basically creates a bookmark for the current range (selection) and then it can be restored via [`CKEDITOR.dom.range.moveToBookmark`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-moveToBookmark).

To make bookmark serializable (so you can save whole content with it to DB and then restore selection when content is loaded), you have to pass `true` to `creatBookmark` like `createBookmark( true )`, this indicates that the bookmark nodes must contain IDs, which can be used to restore the range.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried to use bookmarks but it seems that they are not suitable for my purpose. They are not maintained in the document so that they can be used after the document has been saved and reloaded.

Comment: @Xosted what do you mean that they are not maintained? If you use serialized bookmarks they should be preserved when you fetch data from the editor.

Comment: If so, then I must be doing something wrong. I saved both, bookmark and document, then tried to reach the bookmark again and it fails. I will do some more testing and get back to you.

Comment: So I ran some test and found that passing a bookmark through `JSON.stringify` then `JSON.parse` made it unusable. How would you suggest that I proceed to send a bookmark object to the server side and save it in a db so that I can later load it back and use it to move the selection?

Comment: I got that JSON cannot handle functions in objects so I tried creating another bookmark and copying the data (endNode, startNode, collapsed and serializable) from the parsed string to the new bookmark. However, when trying to move a range to this bookmark, I get the same errors either _a.getParent is not a function_ or _Cannot read property 'getParent' of null_ from `CKEDITOR.dom.range.setStartBefore (ckeditor.js:169)`